# XSLT create new HTML tag

Tags: xslt

How do I create a new HTML tag/node in XSLT ?  I get the node/tag name from another variable.

Comment: I think you mean "create new element", because a node is pretty everything in XML ;)

Answer (score 5):

```
<xsl:element name="{$ELEMENT_NAME}">
  <xsl:attribute name="{$ATTRIBUTE_NAME}">
    <xsl:value-of select="$ATTRIBUTE_VALUE"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
  <content>
    <goes>
      <here/>
    </goes>
  </content>
</xsl:element>
```

**edit:**
You need **{** and **}** for the "name" attributes,
but not for the "select" attribute.

[Read about **here**.](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates)

SORRY! I forgot it myself in first 'version' of the answer.

Comment: One thing: you may want to show how to make the element's name set via a parameter or variable as that is the OP's intention.

Comment: +1 No need for the attribute example though. I know, I know, but the question was about elements only, and the answer does not gain completeness from it. :)